# How can I separate data where no of fields not matching in each row using spark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, txt

I am trying to filter records which donot have expected number of fields in row below is my code

no_of_rows_in_each_column=3
delimiter = ","

input.csv

```
    emp_id,emp_name,salary
    1,"siva 
    Prasad",100
    2,pavan,200,extra
    3,prem,300
    4,john
```

Expecetd output dataframes

Correct_input_data_frame

```
emp_id,emp_name,salary
1,"siva Prasad",100
3,prem,300
```

wrong_file.csv it is file

```
emp_id,emp_name,salary,no_of_fields
2,pavan,200,extra,4 fields in row 3 fields expected
4,john, 2 fields in row 3 expected
```

I tried this, seems able to read but len() function not working on rows.

```
input_df = (spark.read
      .option("multiline", "true")
      .option("quote", '"')
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("escape", "\\")
      .option("escape", '"')
      .csv('input.csv')
)

correct = input_df.(filter(len(row{}) = 3)
wrong_data = input_df.(filter(len(row{})<>3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the schema, then you can use the `columnNameOfCorruptRecord`option.

I've implemented it using Scala, but the Python implementation should be similar.

```scala
val df = spark.read
    .schema("emp_id Long, emp_name String, salary Long, corrupted_record String")
    .option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "corrupted_record")
    .option("multiline", "true")
    .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", false)
    .option("quote", "\"")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("escape", "\\")
    .csv("input.csv")

df.show()
```

The result is:

```
+------+------------+------+-----------------+
|emp_id|    emp_name|salary| corrupted_record|
+------+------------+------+-----------------+
|     1|siva\nPrasad|   100|             null|
|     2|       pavan|   200|2,pavan,200,extra|
|     3|        prem|   300|             null|
|     4|        john|  null|           4,john|
+------+------------+------+-----------------+
```

Now, it is pretty straightforward to filter correct and wrong data:

```scala
val correctDF = df.filter(col("corrupted_record").isNull)
val wrongDF = df.filter(col("corrupted_record").isNotNull)
```

Comment: you are really expert, this helps, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add `DROPMALFORMED` mode to filter out "bad" lines:

```
df = (spark.read
      .option("multiline", "true")
      .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
      .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", False)
      .option("quote", '"')
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("escape", "\\")
      .option("escape", '"')
      .csv('input.csv')
      )
df.show()
```

---

```
+----------+-----------------+------+
|    emp_id|         emp_name|salary|
+----------+-----------------+------+
|         1|siva \n    Prasad|   100|
|         3|             prem|   300|
+----------+-----------------+------+
```

Comment: I want to capture malformed records in another file . Any suggestion?